# Excel Import Data via SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I would need to import the data from SQL Server using SQL query to get the data. I do this via `Connection from Microsoft Query`. The problem is, the data can be only imported as `Table` or `Pivot Table`. I need to import the data which are not formatted as table (due running VBA macro which does not work on data that are in table format).

Is there any option to import the data this way, just pure content?

Comment: You can get `Recordset` object in VBA and get only needed data from it (not whole table). Is it what you need?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the problem ... as in what is the expected data for the VBA code?

Comment: I am using http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail8.htm for sending emails with Excel. The author says it does not work while the data are in table format. However I have created simple workaround - I created simple VBA macro which gets the content from one sheet (data in table format got by SQL query) and copies them into another without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I'm using since long

You can give it a try,

```
select *, ID
from 
OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\MyData.xlsx', sheet1$) where ID IS NULL
```